# Noob clojure misunderstanding: (-> % :foo :bar) vs (:bar :foo)

Tags: clojure

I'm looking through some oo clojure code to better understand it's intricacies.

A lot of the time, when there's a hash map and someone wants to take a key, they write

`(-> % :hash :key)` , where I think they could just write `(:key :hash)`.

I guess my question is, what is `(-> % :hash :key)` doing?

Comment: Some questions for clarification: *someone wants to take a key* Do you mean getting a value using a key? *they write `(-> % :hash :key)`* is `%` supposed to be the hash map? *I think they could just write `(:key :hash)`.* `(:key :hash)` will just evaluate to `nil` Did you mean something else than just the two keywords?

Comment: see "Understanding the Clojure -> macro" - http://blog.fogus.me/2009/09/04/understanding-the-clojure-macro/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->` is the [`Thread-first` macro](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E).

If you have a hash-map like `(def mymap {:foo {:bar "s_bar"}})` then the macro will transform

```
(-> mymap :foo :bar)
```

into

```
(:bar (:foo mymap))
```

and the result will be `"s_bar"`.

Here the macro is used to access values of a nested hash-map and it's similiar to `(get-in mymap [:foo :bar])`